# vim - search for a digraph using its octal value

Tags: vim, hex, octal, digraphs

If I have this digraph character: ň in a file, place the cursor over it and type `ga` I see the message

`<&#328;> 328, Hex 0148, Octal 510`

But then if I search for `/\%o510` or `/%x0148` I get `E486: Pattern not found`

in my vimrc:

`set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8`

How do I search for these characters using either Octal or Hex codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help %o`:

```
%o   Matches the character specified with an octal number up to 0377.
%x   Matches the character specified with up to two hexadecimal characters.
```

Because 0510 octal is greater than 0377, the octal search will not match. Similarly, `%x` admits up to two hexadecimal characters but you need three (148).

Instead use four-character hex-search:

```
%u   Matches the character specified with up to four hexadecimal characters
```

So the pattern is `\%u148`

Comment: Fascinating! Next time I'll remember to study the docs more closely!